# How to Drag an element and drop into a kendoSortable List?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-draggable

I am trying to drag an element from out site of kendoSortable and drop it into kendoSortable.

I set  **connectWith** property of kendoSortable. But it`s not working.

In Kendo UI demo i did not find this kind of example.

Here is my Code :

```
<h1>Sortable</h1>


<ul id="sortable">
      <li class="list-item">Apples</li>
      <li class="list-item">Grapefruits</li>
      <li class="list-item">Bananas</li>
  </ul>

  <h1>Dragable</h1>
  <ul id="dragable">
      <li class="list-item">D1</li>
      <li class="list-item">D2</li>
      <li class="list-item">D3</li>
  </ul>

 <script>
     $("#sortable").kendoSortable({
        connectWith: "#dragable",
        placeholder: function placeholder(element) {
            return $("<li class='list-item' id='placeholder'>Drop Here!</li>");
        },
    });

     $("#dragable li").kendoDraggable({
        hint: function () {
            return $("<li class='list-item' id='placeholder'>GOOOOOO!</li>");
        }
    });

    $("#sortable").kendoDropTarget({
        dragenter: function () {
            console.log("enter");
        },
        dragleave: function () {
            console.log("leve");
        },
        drop: function (e) {

        }
    });
  </script>
```

In [dojo.telerik](http://dojo.telerik.com/OviJ)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your two lists:

```
<h1>Sortable</h1>
<ul id="sortable">
  <li class="list-item">Apples</li>
  <li class="list-item">Grapefruits</li>
  <li class="list-item">Bananas</li>
</ul>

<h1>Dragable</h1>
<ul id="dragable">
  <li class="list-item">D1</li>
  <li class="list-item">D2</li>
  <li class="list-item">D3</li>
</ul>
```

and assuming that you want to copy it from the second (`#draggable`) into the first (`#sortable`), what you should do define `connectWith` in the second (origin of the copy):

```
  $("#sortable").kendoSortable({
      placeholder: function placeholder(element) {
          return $("<li class='list-item' id='placeholder'>Drop Here 1!</li>");
      }
  });

  $("#dragable").kendoSortable({
      connectWith: "#sortable",
      placeholder: function placeholder(element) {
          return $("<li class='list-item' id='placeholder'>Drop Here 2!</li>");
      }
  });
```

Also important to note that `placeholder` probably be defined in both. The first is used when you move from this list while the second is used when the origin is in the second list (no matter if the drop is the first or the second).

You can see it here: http://dojo.telerik.com/@OnaBai/oJIy

Comment: Your solution is works fine. But when i Drag a from dragable collection it remove from dragable Collection. I don`t that. I want drag a copy of item and Drop it in sort-able list with a drop event.

Comment: Is there a way to stop the draggable items from being sortable?
I'd like to use this, but I need the draggable items to remain in the same order.